# How to check if the Application.MainForm is valid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I be sure that in some point of my VCL application lifetime the `Application.MainForm` is valid so I could post a message to it (from a MadExcept ExceptionHandler).

This could be at any point (in the context of any thread) in my application (also `initialization`, `finalization` etc...)

I was thinking:

```
if Assigned(Application)
    and (not Application.Terminated)
    and Assigned(Application.MainForm)
    and Application.MainForm.HandleAllocated then
  begin
    PostMessage(Application.MainForm.Handle, MyMessage, 0, 0);
  end;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: This is not a good design, especially if you need to take threading into account. You should use `AllocateHWnd()` instead to create your own dedicated HWND that you can post your messages to. Don't post them to the `MainForm` window.

Comment: You can check other properties as well but it is stil not a guarantee.  For example ComponentState for csDestroying

Answer (score 3):

> How can I be sure that in some point of my VCL application lifetime the Application.MainForm is valid so I could post a message to it.

OK.

> This could be at any point (in the context of any thread) in my application (also initialization, finalization etc...)

Uh oh.

> ....
>
> Is this correct?

No it certainly is not. Your code can never be made threadsafe because it is not permitted to access VCL objects from outside the main thread.

In your particular case consider the following sequence of events:

1. You perform your tests in the `if` culminating in your evaluating `Application.MainForm.HandleAllocated` as `True`. Ignore for a moment the fact that you are doing this outside the main thread.
2. You then set about preparing the call to `PostMessage`. But at this very instance, the main form is destroyed.
3. By the time your thread gets round to accessing `Application.MainForm`, it has gone.

You are going to need to work a little harder here. You'll need to do something like this:

```
// interface section of some unit

procedure RegisterMainFormHandle(Wnd: HWND);
procedure UnregisterMainFormHandle;
procedure PostMessageToMainForm(...);

// implementation section 

var
  MainFormHandleLock: TCriticalSection;
  MainFormHandle: HWND;

procedure RegisterMainFormHandle(Wnd: HWND);
begin
  MainFormHandleLock.Acquire;
  try
    MainFormHandle := Wnd;
  finally
    MainFormHandleLock.Release;
  end;
end;

procedure UnregisterMainFormHandle;
begin
  MainFormHandleLock.Acquire;
  try
    MainFormHandle := 0;
  finally
    MainFormHandleLock.Release;
  end;
end;

procedure PostMessageToMainForm(...);
begin
  MainFormHandleLock.Acquire;
  try
    if MainFormHandle <> 0 then
      PostMessage(MainFormHandle, ...)
  finally
    MainFormHandleLock.Release;
  end;
end;
```

You also need to create and destroy the critical section, but I assume that you know how to do that.

In your main form you override `CreateWnd` and `DestroyWnd` and arrange that they call `RegisterMainFormHandle` and `UnregisterMainFormHandle`.

Then you can call `PostMessageToMainForm` from any thread at any time.

Of course, if the main form's window is recreated then you'll lose some messages. Which sounds like it could be a problem. Using `AllocateHwnd` to have a window whose lifetime you control is usually a better option than using the main form's window like this.

Comment: sometimes for application with a splash-screen one Mainform is created, then destroyed, then another mainform is created. So even when `Application.MainForm.HandleAllocated` it still might go wrong (be posted to splash screen instead of real main window)

Comment: @Arioch'The Only if the application is designed wrongly. A splash screen is not a main form. Only ever call `Application.CreateForm` once.

Comment: What if the `MainFormHandleLock` already freed in the moment I call `PostMessageToMainForm`? When do you think I need to create/free (and nil) it?

Comment: You have to clean up your threads before finalizing the unit whose finalization will destroy that lock. In other words ensure that the scenario you describe cannot happen.

Comment: for what I remember in D5/D7 any form first to be created was made a main one, including `TForm1.Create(Application)` - splash screen that was displayed before the mainform created was temporarily considered main. IT did not caused premature termination cause it all happened before `Application.Run`

Comment: @David,  its madExcept's exception handling thread. I cannot clean it up. This thread is in the last finalization chain.

Answer (score 0):

Make some global variable flag `= false` at the beginning.

Make your mainform turn it to `true`.

Check that flag to see if main form was already initialised or not yet.

You can make it from such places as mainform's `OnActivate` event or overridden `TMainForm.Loaded` method

Similarly when your application would be terminating and the mainform would get hidden (and later even destroyed) - you would reset the flag back to `false`

Comment: You cannot do this without synchronization. After you have tested the flag, what's to stop the main thread from pulling the rug from under you?

Comment: well, you might make the variable 0-or-HWND instead of Boolean, that would cut some slack. Perfect synchronization is never possible anyway, for you are using PostMessage not SendMessage and the rug can be pulled while the message being enqueued anyway. That latter option should take care of RecreateWND though...